# integrate xmpp server such as openfire to my own java web application

Tags: xmpp, integration

I want to make an iphone application which has chatroom. I searched a lot and think xmpp can do this. But if I use openfire as xmpp server ,how can I integrate openfire to my own java web application server? I think openfire is an independent application and how can it communicate with my java web server?  I searched some similar questions here but still can not understand. Thanks for your help.

Comment: First question is why do you want to integrate it?  Typically a chat app communicates with the XMPP server directly, no web app required.  You need to give more details of what you are trying to accomplish.  Why does your app server need to communicate with the XMPP server?  Is you application a web app (you said it is an iphone app)?

Comment: Yes,it is an iphone app but it needs to get data from the web server. Suppose I need to push notifications to iphone client,how can I get the message sent from iphone client to xmpp server in my web server?

Comment: @Abhinav Maybe something more than that. I　want to get chat info from xmpp server in my java web server application.

Comment: hey did you get solution. I am working on same

Comment: @an5607ky I just use openfire as a standalone chat server at last.

Comment: is it worked properly on openfire server?